# Jquery table row calculations, multiple rows/cols

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an table, the first row stands for months. The next are for the values. I wan't to introduce an aggregation/row calculation method and display it in the last row. Due to the amount of rows and cols, ***I am not quite sure where to start*** with and not repeat the code. *Therefore I am looking for some hints to start off*.

I prepared a mcve for you to see how it looks https://jsfiddle.net/468bguu1/2/

The formula is

Calculations ROW for month 1 is : `(.inc_row_0 + .inc_row_kor_0) - (.exp_row_0 + .exp_row_kor_0 + .work_row_0)`

For convenient calculations I added the classes names, I think thats how it should be done.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline mt-5 table2excel">
          <thead class="btn-primary bg-primary">
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>1</th>
              <th>2</th>
              <th>3</th>
              <th>4</th>
              <th>5</th>
              <th>6</th>
              <th>7</th>
              <th>8</th>
              <th>9</th>
              <th>10</th>
              <th>11</th>
              <th>12</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
              <td>ROW A Σ</td>
              <td class="inc_row_0">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_1">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_2">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_3">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_4">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_5">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_6">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_7">103 091,99</td>
              <td class="inc_row_8">74 247,97</td>
              <td class="inc_row_9">42 660,39</td>
              <td class="inc_row_10">179 264,64</td>
              <td class="inc_row_11">9 693,49</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
              <td>ROW A Adjust</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
              <td class="inc_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
              <td>ROW C</td>
              <td class="exp_row_0">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_1">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_2">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_3">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_4">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_5">387,71</td>
              <td class="exp_row_6">387,71</td>
              <td class="exp_row_7">71 026,92</td>
              <td class="exp_row_8">43 914,10</td>
              <td class="exp_row_9">73 705,35</td>
              <td class="exp_row_10">77 213,29</td>
              <td class="exp_row_11">33,00</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
              <td>ROW C Adjust</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
              <td class="exp_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="btn-primary bg-warning">
              <td>ROW D</td>
              <td class="work_row_0">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_1">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_2">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_3">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_4">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_5">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_6">0,00</td>
              <td class="work_row_7">30 788,44</td>
              <td class="work_row_8">27 522,85</td>
              <td class="work_row_9">25 827,27</td>
              <td class="work_row_10">22 443,28</td>
              <td class="work_row_11">-10 000,60</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
          </tbody>

          <tbody>
            <tr class="btn-primary bg-primary">
              <td>Calculations ROW</td>
              <th class="res_row_0">x</th>
              <th class="res_row_1"></th>
              <th class="res_row_2"></th>
              <th class="res_row_3"></th>
              <th class="res_row_4"></th>
              <th class="res_row_5"></th>
              <th class="res_row_6"></th>
              <th class="res_row_7"></th>
              <th class="res_row_8"></th>
              <th class="res_row_9"></th>
              <th class="res_row_10"></th>
              <th class="res_row_11"></th>

            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

My attempt : ( First have to normalize the text to a float )

```
     for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
   var row_a = parseFloat($(".inc_row_" + i).text().replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.')) + parseFloat($(".inc_row_kor_" + i).text().replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.'));
   var row_b = parseFloat($(".exp_row_" + i).text().replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.')) + parseFloat($(".exp_row_kor_" + i).text().replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.')) + parseFloat($(".work_row_" + i).text().replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.'));
   var calc = row_a - row_b;

   $(".res_row_" + i).text(calc.toFixed(2));
 }
```

Comment: It appears you've made no attempt to solve this yourself and seem to be asking for people to write your code for you. I'd suggest you research the `each()` and `eq()` methods if you want to do this through jQuery

Comment: As mentioned, looking for a start point not the code (:

Comment: Also, while the link to the MCVE code is appreciated that code *must be in the question*, otherwise your question will likely be closed as 'off-topic' (although as currently phrased the question may still be closed as 'too broad').

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/468bguu1/1/, added my attempt. I guess it might be wrong

Comment: `parseFloat($(` is just kind of odd this way why not just use the `i` to create an array of values from the text?

Comment: I think this number format : 179 264,64 can't do calc's

Comment: I understand that you NEED to parse and what you have appears to remove the space and replace the comma for the parse to work, I will post an "answer" to illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

BOTH of these depend on the row cell counts being equal as selected.
This whole "begins with selector" would be better with single class for each "group" of items, making the selector simpler, faster and easier to maintain, but I am not in charge of your layout, just a suggestion.

First this is very verbose option to show how to use a set of arrays with the data in them.  This might have issues as the table changes OR if one of the table "row" things is missing or has an extra `td` which might not be great.

```js
function parseLocalString(localstring) {
  var strippedstring = localstring.replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.');
  var localnumber = parseFloat(strippedstring);
  return localnumber;
}
var myObj = {
  data: {}
}; // hold stuff without a lot of globals
myObj.data = {
  // arrays of numbers
  incRow: [],
  incRowKor: [],
  expRow: [],
  expRowKor: [],
  workRow: [],
  resRow: [],
};
// avoid the fixed 12, just get the stuff
// begins with
$("td[class^='inc_row_']").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).is("td[class^='inc_row_kor_']");
}).each(function() {
  myObj.data.incRow.push(parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});
$("td[class^='inc_row_kor_']").each(function() {
  myObj.data.incRowKor.push(parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});

$("td[class^='exp_row_']").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).is("td[class^='exp_row_kor_']");
}).each(function() {
  myObj.data.expRow.push(parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});
$("td[class^='exp_row_kor_']").each(function() {
  myObj.data.expRowKor.push(parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});

$("td[class^='work_row_']").each(function() {
  myObj.data.workRow.push(parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});

// calculate stuff
for (var i = 0; i < myObj.data.incRow.length; i++) {
  var row_a = myObj.data.incRow[i] + myObj.data.incRowKor[i];
  var row_b = myObj.data.expRow[i] + myObj.data.expRowKor[i] +
  myObj.data.workRow[i];
  var calc = row_a - row_b;
  myObj.data.resRow.push(calc);
}
console.log(myObj.data);
// display results
// odd the 'th' here...
$("th[class^='res_row_']").each(function(index,element) {
console.log(index,myObj.data.resRow[index].toFixed(2));
  $(this).text(myObj.data.resRow[index].toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
table.dataTable {
  width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.mt-5 {
  margin-top: 2rem!important;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1), -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  will-change: box-shadow;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .4rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c!important;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f!important;
}

.bg-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline mt-5 table2excel">
  <thead class="btn-primary bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
      <td>ROW A Σ</td>
      <td class="inc_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_7">103 091,99</td>
      <td class="inc_row_8">74 247,97</td>
      <td class="inc_row_9">42 660,39</td>
      <td class="inc_row_10">179 264,64</td>
      <td class="inc_row_11">9 693,49</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
      <td>ROW A Adjust</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
      <td>ROW C</td>
      <td class="exp_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_5">387,71</td>
      <td class="exp_row_6">387,71</td>
      <td class="exp_row_7">71 026,92</td>
      <td class="exp_row_8">43 914,10</td>
      <td class="exp_row_9">73 705,35</td>
      <td class="exp_row_10">77 213,29</td>
      <td class="exp_row_11">33,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
      <td>ROW C Adjust</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-warning">
      <td>ROW D</td>
      <td class="work_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_7">30 788,44</td>
      <td class="work_row_8">27 522,85</td>
      <td class="work_row_9">25 827,27</td>
      <td class="work_row_10">22 443,28</td>
      <td class="work_row_11">-10 000,60</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-primary">
      <td>Calculations ROW</td>
      <th class="res_row_0">x</th>
      <th class="res_row_1"></th>
      <th class="res_row_2"></th>
      <th class="res_row_3"></th>
      <th class="res_row_4"></th>
      <th class="res_row_5"></th>
      <th class="res_row_6"></th>
      <th class="res_row_7"></th>
      <th class="res_row_8"></th>
      <th class="res_row_9"></th>
      <th class="res_row_10"></th>
      <th class="res_row_11"></th>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<ul>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 1 is : <code>(.inc_row_0 + .inc_row_kor_0) - (.exp_row_0 + .exp_row_kor_0 + .work_row_0)</code></li>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 2 is : <code>(.inc_row_1 + .inc_row_kor_1) - (.exp_row_1 + .exp_row_kor_1 + .work_row_1)</code></li>
  <li>etc.</li>
</ul>

<br> Basic idea <code>res_row_{n} = (.inc_row_{n} + .inc_row_kor_{n}) - (.exp_row_{n} + .exp_row_kor_{n} + .work_row_{n})</code>
```

Now for this one, we avoid the global object and arrays, just putting the values of the table "cells" as data on each one, inserting the value at the end.

```js
function parseLocalString(localstring) {
  var strippedstring = localstring.replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.');
  var localnumber = parseFloat(strippedstring);
  return localnumber;
}
  
// avoid the fixed 12, just get the stuff
// begins with
$("td[class^='inc_row_']").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).is("td[class^='inc_row_kor_']");
}).each(function() {
  // put it right on the cell
  $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});
$("td[class^='inc_row_kor_']").each(function() {
  // put it right on the cell
  $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});

$("td[class^='exp_row_']").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).is("td[class^='exp_row_kor_']");
}).each(function() {
  // put it right on the cell
  $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});
$("td[class^='exp_row_kor_']").each(function() {
  // put it right on the cell
  $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});

$("td[class^='work_row_']").each(function() {
  // put it right on the cell
  $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
});
// odd th here
$("th[class^='res_row_']").each(function(index, elem) {
  var row_a = $("td[class^='inc_row_']").eq(index).data('parsedval') + $("td[class^='inc_row_kor_']").eq(index).data('parsedval') * 1;
  // get from the cells
  var row_b = $("td[class^='exp_row_']").eq(index).data('parsedval') + $("td[class^='exp_row_kor']").eq(index).data('parsedval') + $("td[class^='work_row_']").eq(index).data('parsedval') * 1;
  var calc = row_a - row_b;
  console.log(index,calc.toFixed(2));
  $(elem).data('parsedval', calc.toFixed(2));
  $(elem).text(calc.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
table.dataTable {
  width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.mt-5 {
  margin-top: 2rem!important;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1), -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  will-change: box-shadow;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .4rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c!important;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f!important;
}

.bg-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline mt-5 table2excel">
  <thead class="btn-primary bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
      <td>ROW A Σ</td>
      <td class="inc_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_7">103 091,99</td>
      <td class="inc_row_8">74 247,97</td>
      <td class="inc_row_9">42 660,39</td>
      <td class="inc_row_10">179 264,64</td>
      <td class="inc_row_11">9 693,49</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
      <td>ROW A Adjust</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
      <td class="inc_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
      <td>ROW C</td>
      <td class="exp_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_5">387,71</td>
      <td class="exp_row_6">387,71</td>
      <td class="exp_row_7">71 026,92</td>
      <td class="exp_row_8">43 914,10</td>
      <td class="exp_row_9">73 705,35</td>
      <td class="exp_row_10">77 213,29</td>
      <td class="exp_row_11">33,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger">
      <td>ROW C Adjust</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_7">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_8">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_9">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_10">0,00</td>
      <td class="exp_row_kor_11">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-warning">
      <td>ROW D</td>
      <td class="work_row_0">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_1">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_2">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_3">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_4">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_5">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_6">0,00</td>
      <td class="work_row_7">30 788,44</td>
      <td class="work_row_8">27 522,85</td>
      <td class="work_row_9">25 827,27</td>
      <td class="work_row_10">22 443,28</td>
      <td class="work_row_11">-10 000,60</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-primary">
      <td>Calculations ROW</td>
      <th class="res_row_0">x</th>
      <th class="res_row_1"></th>
      <th class="res_row_2"></th>
      <th class="res_row_3"></th>
      <th class="res_row_4"></th>
      <th class="res_row_5"></th>
      <th class="res_row_6"></th>
      <th class="res_row_7"></th>
      <th class="res_row_8"></th>
      <th class="res_row_9"></th>
      <th class="res_row_10"></th>
      <th class="res_row_11"></th>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<ul>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 1 is : <code>(.inc_row_0 + .inc_row_kor_0) - (.exp_row_0 + .exp_row_kor_0 + .work_row_0)</code></li>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 2 is : <code>(.inc_row_1 + .inc_row_kor_1) - (.exp_row_1 + .exp_row_kor_1 + .work_row_1)</code></li>
  <li>etc.</li>
</ul>

<br> Basic idea <code>res_row_{n} = (.inc_row_{n} + .inc_row_kor_{n}) - (.exp_row_{n} + .exp_row_kor_{n} + .work_row_{n})</code>
```

**LOOK HERE!:** OK we have progress so let's just use single classes simpler to consolidate code and using this and make it faster in the process.

```js
function parseLocalString(localstring) {
  var strippedstring = localstring.replace(/ /g, '').replace(',', '.');
  var localnumber = parseFloat(strippedstring);
  return localnumber;
}

// NO MORE begins with, easier using groups by row

$(".inc_row")
  .add(".inc_row_kor")
  .add(".exp_row")
  .add(".exp_row_kor")
  .add(".work_row")
  .find('.rowdata').each(function() {
    // put it right on the cell
    $(this).data('parsedval', parseLocalString($(this).text()));
  });

// odd th here
$(".res_row").find('.rowdata').each(function(index, elem) {
  var row_a = $(".inc_row").find('.rowdata').eq(index).data('parsedval') + $(".inc_row_kor").find('.rowdata').eq(index).data('parsedval') * 1;
  // get from the cells
  var row_b = $(".exp_row").find('.rowdata').eq(index).data('parsedval') + $(".exp_row_kor").find('.rowdata').eq(index).data('parsedval') +$(".work_row").find('.rowdata').eq(index).data('parsedval') * 1;
  var calc = row_a - row_b;
  console.log(index, calc.toFixed(2));
  $(elem).data('parsedval', calc.toFixed(2));
  $(elem).text(calc.toFixed(2));
});
```

```css
table.dataTable {
  width: 100%!important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.mt-5 {
  margin-top: 2rem!important;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1), -webkit-box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  will-change: box-shadow;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .4rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c!important;
}

.bg-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f!important;
}

.bg-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline mt-5 table2excel">
  <thead class="btn-primary bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success inc_row">
      <td>ROW A Σ</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">103 091,99</td>
      <td class="rowdata">74 247,97</td>
      <td class="rowdata">42 660,39</td>
      <td class="rowdata">179 264,64</td>
      <td class="rowdata">9 693,49</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-success inc_row_kor">
      <td>ROW A Adjust</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger exp_row">
      <td>ROW C</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">387,71</td>
      <td class="rowdata">387,71</td>
      <td class="rowdata">71 026,92</td>
      <td class="rowdata">43 914,10</td>
      <td class="rowdata">73 705,35</td>
      <td class="rowdata">77 213,29</td>
      <td class="rowdata">33,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="btn-primary bg-danger exp_row_kor">
      <td>ROW C Adjust</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-warning work_row">
      <td>ROW D</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">0,00</td>
      <td class="rowdata">30 788,44</td>
      <td class="rowdata">27 522,85</td>
      <td class="rowdata">25 827,27</td>
      <td class="rowdata">22 443,28</td>
      <td class="rowdata">-10 000,60</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="btn-primary bg-primary res_row">
      <td>Calculations ROW</td>
      <th class="rowdata">x</th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
      <th class="rowdata"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<ul>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 1 is : <code>(.inc_row_0 + .inc_row_kor_0) - (.exp_row_0 + .exp_row_kor_0 + .work_row_0)</code></li>
  <li>Calculations ROW for month 2 is : <code>(.inc_row_1 + .inc_row_kor_1) - (.exp_row_1 + .exp_row_kor_1 + .work_row_1)</code></li>
  <li>etc.</li>
</ul>

<br> Basic idea <code>res_row_{n} = (.inc_row_{n} + .inc_row_kor_{n}) - (.exp_row_{n} + .exp_row_kor_{n} + .work_row_{n})</code>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Working with `<tr>`s id (dynamic)**
First, you need to know which row you will work with, add one ID for each:
`<tr class="btn-primary bg-success" id="inc_tr">`
After that, you can use jQuery [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function (use $(this) to work with every `<td>`):

```
$("tr#inc_tr").each(function(trIndex) {
  $("td", this).each(function(tdIndex) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

And don't forget to remove the first one (or the "title").

---

**Working with loop of `<td>`s id/class (static)**

You can work with loop, too. Just need to make it work with the index after every `<td>`s id, but you will need one static value:

```
for(var id = 0; id<=11; id++){
    console.log($(".inc_row_"+id).text());
}
```

As they are unique tags, it's better if you work with `id`, not `class`:

```
<td id="inc_row_0">0,00</td>
```

And the loop:

```
for(var id = 0; id<=11; id++){
    console.log($("#inc_row_"+id).text());
}
```

---

**Working with columns**

Here you can work with class, but I will recommend you to set the same class for every cell in the column:

```
<tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
  <td>ROW A Σ</td>
  <td class="inc_col_0">0,00</td>
    ...
<tr class="btn-primary bg-success">
  <td>ROW A Adjust</td>
  <td class="inc_col_0">0,00</td>
```

Now, you can perform [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function again, and search for the class of `<tr>`:

```
$("tr").each(function( indexTr ) {
  console.log($(this).find('td.inc_col_0').text());
});
```

Or, you can try with [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), this one will return you the (x+1)th column. Example with the second column:

```
$("tr").each(function( indexTr ) {
  console.log($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
});
```

Comment: That's what I did as you see, what about the repetition and field normalization? Its not so neat attempt right?

Comment: Field normalization is always good. But you need to work the way that suits you better. :)

Comment: Yes, I got 179 264,64 such formats. Is my way good or is there any better one?

Comment: Now that you got your number, you just need to parse it. [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) should work if you replace the blankspace and comma, something like `.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.')`.

Comment: `$("tr#inc_tr").each(` This is NOT needed, since and ID **MUST** be unique use ONLY `$("#inc_tr").find('td').each(function(tdIndex`

Comment: Securing is always the best option. :)